# How to create matrix in matlab, octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have vector like V[5000,1]  with values in range 1-10
How to get matrix W[5000,10]

```
V[1]   W[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2]   W[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [10]  W[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [7]   W[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 ...    ...
```

its like W have "1" in column indicated by vector V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You can use the following approach:

```
W = zeros(length(v),10);
W(sub2ind(size(W),1:length(v),v'))=1;
```

**Results**

```
v = [10,4,10,4,9]

W =
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Also there was good alternative answer from gnovice. Too bad, but he decided to delete it. (

Comment: @AndrewM: Since it's a duplicate, I added it to the original instead.